# Can I copy files from Sharepoint to Azure Blob Storage using dynamic file path?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-synapse, dynamic-parallelism

I am building a pipeline to copy files from Sharepoint to Azule Blob Storage at work.
After reading some documentation, I was able to create a pipeline that only copies certain files.
However, I would like to automate this pipeline by using dynamic file paths to specify the source files in Sharepoint.
In other words, when I run the pipeline on 2022/07/14, I want to get the files from the Sharepoint folder named for that day, such as "Data/2022/07/14/files".
I know how to do this with PowerAutomate, but my company does not want me to use PowerAutomate.
The current pipeline looks like the attached image.
Do I need to use parameters in the URL of the source dataset?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

You can create a parameterized dataset as below
[image]

[image]

Then from the copy activity you can give the file path to this parameter
as

```
@concat('Data/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'))
```

[image]